Comparing two dates across the century on one Excel spreadsheet. Getting data mismatch?
I have asked this question before and was deleted because of insufficient information.  I'll try better this time.
The spreadsheet has two dates (Birth, Death).  I'm trying to figure out how many years, months and days between the two dates.
the format of the two columns is m/dd/yyyy and all show the full year as 4 digits. The macro code is a follow:
Sub calc()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim M As Integer
    Dim D As Integer
    Dim startdate As Date
    Dim enddate As Date
    Dim datetext As String
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    startdate = Format(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2), "DD/MM/YYYY")
    enddate = Format(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3), "DD/MM/YYYY")
    datatext = DateDiff(startdate, enddate, "Y") & " years " & DateDiff(startdate, enddate, "YD") & " days"
'Years
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5) = DateDiff("yyyy", dob, dt)
'Months
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6) = DateDiff("m", dbo, dt)
'Days
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7) = DateDiff("d", dob, dt)
End Sub

I tried to include the spreadsheet but I'm not sure how to get in the question.  It is basically as follows:
Name | Birth | Death | Years | Months | Days

With the Birth of 04/08/1945 and death at 12/9/2024 I would expect it to have Col 4=79, col 5=3 and col 6=1.  But I keep getting

'TYPE MISMATCH' on line startdate = Format(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2), "DD/MM/YYYY")

If I display those dates in the immediate window I get 04/08/1945 in Birth and 12/9/24 in Death thus I guess the data mismatch.

startdate and enddate are of type Date. The cells containing the dates are formatted as Date, too. Therefore you can simply delete the Format function in line 7 and 8.

You're starting with Dates and then converting them to Strings and trying use DateDiff on them.  Instead of converting them, just use them "as is".

Stringeater, I commented out the Format statements and still got the same error  "Type error 13"

Frank Ball, I didn't convert to strings they are all defined as DATES. If I comment out the Format statements and datetext line I get zeros in the Year, Month and Day cells.

Start by reading the MS HELP topic for Datediff. Both your syntax and arguments are incorrect and is the cause of your error messasge. Although you, as is good practice, declared your variables, you should put Option Explicit at the top of your module. This will pickup your typo (although it is not the cause of your error). In the VBA GUI, you can enforce this by Tools/Options/Editor/Code Settings and selecting Require Variable Declaration. And, as mentioned by @Stringeater, formatting your date data as text is unneccesary, and can cause errors if the default date format changes.

Oh, and the reason you get zero's when you comment out the Format statements is because you never set anything equal to dob or dt. Hence that formula reduces to:  DateDiff(*interval*, 0, 0). Again this is something you would have caught had you used Option Explicit

Just to clarify, the DateDiff formula that is causing the type mismatch error is the first one: datatext = DateDiff(startdate, enddate, "Y") & " years " & DateDiff(startdate, enddate, "YD") & " days"

col 5=3 ? Not 8 ?

Apparently I'm not making myself clear.  I am trying to determine the number of years, months, and days between two dates in an Excel spreadsheet.  The total full years, the balance of months, and the balance of days for the total added up to the total between the two dates.  I thought I could do it with datediff but it appears that the format gives you the total years but then it gives you the total of all the months between and all the days between and not a difference that I'm looking for.

@user3022578 what happened when you made the alterations to your code that I suggested in my comments to correct the errors and your undeclared and undefined variables?

@user3022578 also, since both years and months have a variable number of days, how are you defining them for this purpose. Also, what are your rules for the birthday of a leapling?

Sub calc()

    Dim dtBirth As Date, dtDeath As Date
    Dim y As Long, m As Long, d As Long
    
    With ActiveCell.EntireRow
        dtBirth = .Columns(2)
        dtDeath = .Columns(3)
    End With
    
    y = DateDiff("YYYY", dtBirth, dtDeath)
    dt = DateAdd("YYYY", y, dtBirth)
    If dt > dtDeath Then
        y = y - 1
        dt = DateAdd("YYYY", -1, dt)
    End If
    
    m = DateDiff("m", dt, dtDeath)
    dt = DateAdd("m", m, dt)
    If dt > dtDeath Then
        m = m - 1
        dt = DateAdd("m", -1, dt)
    End If
    
    d = DateDiff("d", dt, dtDeath)

    MsgBox y & " " & m & " " & d
End Sub

